# TIZEN STUDIO NATIVE SIGN BUILD ISSUE

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, tizen, tizen-tv

I made one application in Tizen studio and created a signed certificate(Author and distributer).

So now I want to create a signed package and send it to someone.

How to do that can anyone guide me?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send someone your signed app it's very easy and you only need to right click on your project name and select "Build signed package"

But be aware your signed app can only be use directly into yours linked devices via SDK and no one could install it in other devices (at least, [not directly](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/support/documentation-qa/developing-applications-qa.html)).

The only two ways to use your app in real devices without SDK tools is publishing your app into the seller platform or through USB using the "Demo Packaging Tool" if your are a [Samsung partner](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/distribute/seller-office/membership/partnership-request.html)

You should check more about [signing flow](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/tutorials/sign-certificate/) and [publication process](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/distribute/application-publication-process.html)